# React how to render page after query change in URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm facing a problem :

I access a URL, for example:

http://localhost:900/user

In my page i have an array. When I click on an pagination button for change page in array, my fonction changePage is called, the URL changes for add search query, my page re render because i use setState({page}), so far so good. New URL : http://localhost:900/user?page=2  (Attention the pathname has not changed, i just add search query)

If i click on next page again, the url change to http://localhost:900/user?page=3 and my page re render. It's perfect.

Now, i press the back button in the Browser, the location changes back to http://localhost:900/user?page=2 but the page does not re render.

How to re render page if user press the back button in the Browser and not on the last page on application ?

I use :
react : "16.3.2",
react-dom : "16.3.2",
react-redux : "5.0.7",
react-router-dom : "4.2.2",

EDIT: 
when i use listen function after create BrowserHistory, and i press previous browser page:

```
const history = createBrowserHistory();
history.listen((location, action) => {
  // location is an object like window.location
  console.log(action, location.search);
});
```

the location.search was good.

My problem is only when i use the arrows of the browser in the same page. When i go in other page and i go back to the page, the url is good to and my array is reload with the good informations

Comment: did you setState in listener?

Comment: when I click on the button next page of my table, i call function fetchDatas. In this function i call an action for fetchData and i use setState. In setState callback, i call other function that use this.props.history.push('/{yourNewUrl}')

Comment: I have created this https://codesandbox.io/s/z226wn416m and the `Main` component always rerendered when query string changed. Have a look at that.

Comment: thanks, i'm going to start modifying my code to try your solution. I will keep you informed.

Comment: but your history listener should change the state of your component. browser's back button is not invoking any state change in your component.

Comment: I assume fetchData is dependent on the page number. so your listener component should `setState(page)` then call function fetchData. after that it is not even necessary to call the fetchData from your next button's click callback. this.props.history.push('/yourNewUrl') will invoke the fetch from listener.

Comment: @Pravin The person who dev this software create a component Table. In page userList he pass information by props for Table component nottament the property numberUser. He use this props for calculate the number of page and generate the pagination. He create function for change page and he save the number of current page in state. This is the reason why he use setState. When i use button of array for navigate all get other user, it works perfectly. When i click on user, the page detail work and when i press previous page browser i reback on the good last page.

Comment: @im_tsm nice idea but she don't work in my case

Comment: @A.Vincent can you upload the bare code with logic discarded from it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183501/discussion-between-a-vincent-and-pravin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try listening on the 'popstate' event handler :

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", () => {
  // React state change logic
});
```

From MDN: The popstate event is fired when the active history entry changes. If the history entry being activated was created by a call to history.pushState() or was affected by a call to history.replaceState(), the popstate event's state property contains a copy of the history entry's state object.

Comment: thx you so much. i have call this function on componentDidMount() and removeEventListener in componentWillUnmount()

Answer (score 0):

On the function you are using to route, have you tried: `this.props.history.push('/{yourNewUrl}')` ?

Comment: Yes, in my function i use this.props.history.push('/{yourNewUrl}') it's for this my url was good when i press previuos button in the browser. But my page does not re render.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put appropriate cache-control headers in your response headers -

```
cache-control: private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
```